# Switching between viewControllers manually

Tags: objective-c

I am in `viewcontroller1` and i want to go to `viewcontroller2` , in `1` i do :

```
UIViewController *sv=[[signUpView alloc]init];
[self addChildViewController:sv];
```

Where `signUpView` is the new viewController `class`(subclass of `view controller`)
Nothing is happens .

I tried :     `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`
which did worked and removed my view.

1. how do i do transition to 2
2. how do i add 2 on 1 and than go back to 1 ?

Thanks .

Comment: why you are not using pushviewcontroller or present presentviewcontroller. for return to V1, you will get a back button(pushviewcontroller). or dismissviewcontroller with presentviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is:

```
    [ParentViewController.view addSubview: ChildViewController.view];
    [ParentViewController addChildViewController: ChildViewController];
    [ChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController: ParentViewController];
```

In your case, it would be:

```
    [self.view addSubview: sv.view];
    [self addChildViewController: sv];
    [sv didMoveToParentViewController: self];
```

Also see the [View Controller Containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) article on Apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with:

```
UIViewController *sv=[[signUpView alloc]init];
[self addChildViewController:sv];
[self.view addSubview:sv.view];
[sv didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I don't put any comment because this code is self explanatory.
That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to setup your `UIViewController` interactions in your Storyboard using segues and then programmatically call the segue. If you are not sure how to setup a segue then take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) by Ray Wenderlich or search for one; there are plenty out there and anything I write would pale by comparison.

Since everything is configured in the storyboard, the code is simple. This is my example of `viewController1` making the call to switch to `viewController2`.

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"DoNumber2" sender:self];`