# Loading another viewController programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have asked a question here about this issue ,
[Switching between viewControllers manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704675/switching-between-viewcontrollers-manually)

I have tried what was suggested with:

//add view to the current view

```
UIViewController *sv=[[PromotionView alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview: sv.view];
[self addChildViewController: sv];
[sv didMoveToParentViewController: self];
```

Where the next view is another viewcontroller class that related to a view in `storyboard.`

What really happens is that the `viewDidLoad` method of the next viewController is executed , but the current view is stay, and i don't see the next view on screen.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the view a name ID in storyboard , than just simply do :

```
UIViewController *sv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ServiceListView"];

  [self.view addSubview: sv.view];
  [self addChildViewController: sv];
  [sv didMoveToParentViewController: self];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to present that viewcontroller instead of addchild to show that viewcontroller on screen check below for presenting viewcontroller:

import PromotionView class do following thing:

> PromotionView *sv=[[PromotionView
>   alloc]initWithNibName:@"PromotionView" bundle:nil];
>
> [self presentModalViewController:earningStmtViewController
>   animated:YES];

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. i don't work with nib files

Comment: @Curnelious check my edited answer now it is ok? and thank for helping to improve answer